# Дозапись файла новыми данными

Tags: c++, файлы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в файле уже имеются данные и в него нужно записать новые, при этом чтобы старые не удалились. В моем случае старые данные удаляются и вместо них записывается новая строка.

```
#include <fstream>
...
ofstream fout;
fout.open("file.txt");
...
fout << "abcd";
fout.close();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У метода `open` есть второй параметр, который определяет способ работы с файлом. Нужно задать режим `app` - запись в конец:

```
open("file.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::app);
```